# System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY, Owner ID: owner cannot be blank: [OwnerId]

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

I wanted to write test class for Triger which insert contact on user Insertion. So I am writing test class to check whether new created contact is related to that user or not but Im receiving error. sharing my trigger and the error is in a test class. can somebody please help me understand to get rid of this error.

Trigger:

```
trigger BeforeInsertUseronCondeleteTrigger on User (before Insert , after Insert) {
    if(Trigger.isBefore && Trigger.isInsert) {
        BeforeInsertUseronCondeleteHandler.PreventContactAddition(Trigger.new);
    }
     if(Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
        BeforeInsertUseronCondeleteHandler.PreventContactAddition(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

Handler:

```
public class BeforeInsertUseronCondeleteHandler {
    public static void PreventContactAddition(List<User> newList){
    Set<String> emailSet = new Set<String>();
    List<Contact> contact = new List<Contact>();
    Final String errMsg = 'The email already exists on another Record: ';
    
    for( User u : newList ) emailSet.add( u.Email );
    Map< String, Id > duplicateContactMap = new Map< String, Id >();
    
    for( Contact c : [select Id, Email from Contact where Email = :emailSet] )
        duplicateContactMap.put( c.Email, c.Id );
    
    for( User u : newList ){
        Id duplicateContactId = duplicateContactMap.get( u.Email );
        if( duplicateContactId != null ){
            u.addError( errMsg + duplicateContactId );
        }
        else if( Trigger.isAfter && Trigger.isInsert) {
            Contact con = new Contact(LastName = u.LastName,OwnerId=u.Id, Email=u.Email);
            contact.add(con);
        }
    }
    
        Insert contact;
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
@isTest
public class BeforeInsertUseronCondeleteTriggerTest {
    
    @testSetup static void setup() {
        List<User> lstUser= new List<User>();
        Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'System Administrator'];
        // Creating common test User
        User u = new User();
        u.Alias = 'ttgtt';
        u.Email = 'test6453@example.com';
        u.EmailEncodingKey = 'UTF-8';
        u.LastName = 'Test';
        u.LanguageLocaleKey = 'en_US';
        u.LocaleSidKey = 'en_US';
        u.TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles';
        u.ProfileId = p.Id;
        u.UserName='testtryegtptktutstdu@yaahooooo.com';
        lstUser.add(u);
        
        // Creating common test Contacts
        List<Contact> lstCon = new List<Contact>();
        Contact objCon = new Contact();
        objCon.LastName = 'Test1';
        objCon.OwnerId = u.Id;
        objCon.Email=u.Email;
        lstcon.add(objCon);
        Insert lstCon;       
    }
    
    @isTest static void testConOnAcc()
    { 
        
        User u = [SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE UserName='testtryegtptktutstdu@yaahooooo.com' LIMIT 1];
        Contact conObj = [SELECT Id, Email, OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE LastName='Test1' AND OwnerId=:u.Id LIMIT 1];
        System.runAs(u){
        Test.startTest();
        System.assertEquals('test6453@example.com', conObj.Email);
        Test.stopTest();
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: In the Test Class `lstUser.add(u);` after this line add `insert lstUser;` and try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following this line:

```
lstUser.add(u);
```

You would want to insert the user. To do this without an error, you also need to run it as a simulated user.

```
lstUser.add(u);
System.runAs(new User(Id=UserInfo.getUserId())) {
  insert lstUser;
}
```